# Using Amazon API/Webservice for search product by UPC barcode

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

Scenario:
The user can put in a UPC barcode in a field and press a button, then the software will look online to see if it can find the item on Amazon

How can I and which Amazon API/webservice should I to get product detail by UPC barcode